# Correct SPF for using google-apps with additional outbound mailserver

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, g-suite, spf

[Asked this on stackoverflow and was referred here]

We are developing a custom web app for a client. This app is on a separate server, server.com, than the client's web site, www.client.com. Each user of our app has an email address like user1@client.com, user2@client.com, etc. The client is using Google Apps for business for their user emails (like user1@client.com).

Now here's what we need: Each user needs to be able to send certain emails to people on his contact list. Those emails are from our box, server.com. But we want the From and Reply-To address to be the user who sent it, e.g., user2@client.com.

How can we set up our box, server.com, to be an authorized sender of emails from "client.com"? I looked up the SPF record for Google apps, and it is:

v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

(1) How do we add "server.com" to this SPF record?

(2) From PHP, how can we ensure that the email, while sent from our server.com, still says "From: user2@client.com"?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure SPF for multiple domains on a server? (also allowing gmail as a sender)](http://serverfault.com/questions/4354/how-do-i-configure-spf-for-multiple-domains-on-a-server-also-allowing-gmail-as)

Answer (score 3):

```
v=spf1 a:server.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

That allows the device(s) that `server.com` resolves to.

---

PHP builds the message envelope completely independently of the hostname of the device that it's sent from.  Set the headers correctly in your code, the SMTP relay that it comes from is of no significance for the apparent sender.